# defmethod with list type

Tags: methods, types, lisp, common-lisp

Is it possible in Common Lisp to define a method with a "list type"?

```lisp
(defgeneric show (obj))

(defmethod show ((obj coordinate)) ;; Works
  ...)
(defmethod show ((obj [LIST OF coordinate])) ;; How to?
  ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a method on `list` type but not on arbitrary type specifiers. From hyperspec:

> If parameter-specializer-name is a symbol it names a class;
> if it is a list, it is of the form (eql eql-specializer-form).

Related question: [Defmethod on Arbitrary Type Specifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085443/defmethod-on-arbitrary-type-specifiers/27089364)

Something like this might work for you:

```
(defmethod show ((obj coordinate))
  ...)

(defmethod show ((obj null)))
(defmethod show ((obj cons))  ;; Or just loop it.
  (show (car obj))
  (show (cdr obj)))
```

Comment: Yes thats it!
In my case i just had to
`(defmethod show ((obj null)) "")` and 
`(defmethod show ((obj cons))
  (concatenate 'string (show (car obj)) (show (cdr obj))))
`